# Largest quotient of solvability length 2

Tags: gr.group-theory

I've been thinking about quotients of groups, and I know that the abelianization G/[G,G] is important, but what about other quotients? Specifically, what about the quotient G/[G,[G,G]]? Is that important? More specifically I want to know about the quotient G/[G,[G,G]] if G is the free group on two generators. Is there a name for it?

Edit: Silly me, I just worked out this is just the discrete heisenberg group. The group G/[[G,G],[G,G]] is the group I want to know about now.

Comment: That would be the relatively free metabelian group of rank two. So... should the title of your question be "Largest quotient of solvability length 2"?

Comment: Is there an easy way to describe it? What is its structure?

Comment: Actually, I've realised that since the groups of nilpotency class 3 are a lot easier than the groups of derived length 2, so I will look at those first.

Comment: The relatively free groups in the variety of nilpotent groups of class $c$ are fairly easy to describe in terms of the basic commutators; you can find all the details you need in Hall's *Theory of Groups*, or in the papers of Golovin and of R.R. Struik from the 60s discussing "nilpotent products of groups". For the free metabelian group, as I recall there are some standard ways of representing *any* torsion free metabelian group as a group of matrices.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that after trying to do it myself. The metabelian group seems to be a lot harder though, and I realised that there would be infinitely many of the basic commutators, so that wasn't going to work.

Comment: In the relatively free metabelian group, the basic commutators generate a subgroup of $[G,G]$ of infinite index. Again, Hanna Neumann's book has a lot of stuff, including that the basic commutators don't generate the commutator subgroup in that situation, and results about the relatively free metabelian groups (and relatively free metabelian nilpotent groups of class $c$). If you want to play around with these things, that book is a must.

Comment: Where can I get Hanna Neumann's book?

Comment: Your friendly university library? I just did a search in Bookfinders and got 32 hits, including 13 "new" (Abebooks offering it as print-on-demand).

Answer (score 5):

Given any set of words $\mathfrak{W}$, and a group $G$, the subgroup $\mathfrak{W}(G)$ generated by all values of the words in $\mathfrak{W}$ evaluated at elements of $G$ is a fully invariant subgroup of $G$ called the $\mathfrak{W}$-verbal subgroup of $G$. It is the smallest normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ satisfies the words in $\mathfrak{W}$, i.e., such that $G$ lies in the variety of groups determined by $\mathfrak{W}$.

For instance, if $\mathfrak{W}=\{ xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\} = \{[x,y]\}$, then $\mathfrak{W}$ determines the variety of abelian groups, and $\mathfrak{W}(G)=[G,G]$ is the commutator subgroup. If $\mathfrak{W}=\{ [x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]\}$, then $\mathfrak{W}$ determines the variety of nilpotent groups of class at most $n$, and $\mathfrak{W}(G) = G_{n+1}$, the $n+1$st term of the lower central series.

If $G$ is the free group on $k$ generators, then $G/\mathfrak{W}(G)$ is the *relatively free $\mathfrak{W}$-group of rank $k$*. It has the same universal property as the free group of rank $k$, but relative to groups in the variety determined by $\mathfrak{W}$.

**Added:** If we take the word $[[x,y],[z,w]]$, then this determines the variety of metabelian groups, $\mathfrak{A}^2$ (equivalently: solvable groups of solvability length at most two). The verbal subgroup corresponding to $[[x,y],[z,w]]$ is $G^{(2)}$, the second derived subgroup of $G$. If ${F}$ is the free group of rank $2$, then $F/[[F,F],[F,F]] = F/F^{(2)}$ is **the relatively free metabelian group of rank $2$**; it has the universal property that given any solvable group $K$ with solvability length at most $2$, and any elements $a,b\in K$, there exists a unique group homomorphism $F/F^{(2)} \to K$ that maps the free generators $x$, $y$ to $a$ and $b$, respectively.

For much more on this, see Hanna Neumann's book *Varieties of Groups*.

Comment: It seems that (at least when taken on free groups) that the groups G/W(G) are a generalization of the free burnside groups.

Comment: @Thomas: The free Burnside groups are a special case of this general construction: they arise as the relatively free groups of the variety determined by the word $x^n$ for different values of $n$. This is discussed in Hanna Neumann's book at length.

Comment: @Thomas: Just a caveat: Golovin refers to groups of nilpotency class 2 as "metabelian"; that's an older usage.